# How to initialize a double dimensional boolean array/char array with fill function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I want to initialize a double dimensional array of bool type with true value .

`bool a[5][5] = {true}; //Well this won't work`

```
fill(a,a+sizeof(a),true); // This throws an error too.
```

how to get this done ?

Comment: I think a *good* solution using the C++ Standard Library requires (multi-dimensional) array views, as proposed in [N3976](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3976.html).

Comment: You might be able to get away with `std:fill(&a[0][0],&a[4][4]+1,true)`. This is evil and not strictly legal C++ but it usually works, so...

Comment: @n.m. why isn't it strictly legal ?

Comment: @Benoit this starts with a pointer that points into an array `a[0]` and then eventually goes out of bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool a[5][5] {{true, true, true, true, true},
              {true, true, true, true, true},
              {true, true, true, true, true},
              {true, true, true, true, true},
              {true, true, true, true, true}};
```

Correct, but fragile – when you change size of the array without changing the `true, true, true...` part, added part of array will be initialized using `false`.

You'd better simply use for loop to do this:

```
bool a[5][5];
for (auto& r: a)
    for (bool& b: r)
        b = true;
```

or use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool> > a(5, {true, true, true, true, true});
```

Comment: `vector<bool>` is evil, since it's a special-case space optimized container (bitflags). If you want to use it nevertheless, you could initialize it using `std::vector<std::vector<bool>> a(5, std::vector<bool>(5, true));`